# How to show that f(x)=(x+1)/(x-1) is its own inverse by computing f(f(x))

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Basically, I need to show that f(x)=(x+1)/(x-1) is its own inverse by computing f(f(x)). I can set up the problem, but I have run into a road block for proving it is its own inverse.

Comment: So you have
$$\frac{\frac{x+1}{x-1}+1}{\frac{x+1}{x-1}-1}.$$ What happens when you multiply both the denominator and the numerator with $x-1$?

Comment: Have you done the computation showing that $f(f(x))=x$?

Comment: Thank you! I actually did it correctly but I did not know f(f(x))=x. Shows the gaps that occur in some math courses!

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just computing that ?  If for any $x$, $f ( f (x) ) = x$, $f$ is its own inverse function.

$$
f(f(x)) =
\frac{f(x)+1}{f(x)-1} = \frac{\frac{x+1}{x-1}+1}{\frac{x+1}{x-1}-1} = \frac{\frac{x+1+(x-1)}{x-1}}{\frac{x+1-(x-1)}{x-1}} = 
\frac{x+1+(x-1)}{x+1-(x-1)}
=\frac{2 \cdot x}{2} = x.
$$